# How to use the host network, and any other user-defined network together in Docker-Compose?

Tags: docker, networking, service, docker-compose, ethernet

I want to connect two Docker containers, defined in a Docker-Compose file to each other (`app` and `db`). And one of them (`app`) should also be connected to the `host` network.

The containers should be connected to a common user-defined network (`appnet` or `default`) to use the *embedded DNS* capabilities from docker networking.

`app` needs also to be directly connected to the host network to receive ethernet broadcasts (network layer 2) in the physical network of the docker host.

Using both directives `network_mode: host` and `networks` in compose together, results in the following error:

`ERROR: 'network_mode' and 'networks' cannot be combined`

Specifying the network name `host` in the service without defining it in networks (because it already exists), results in:

`ERROR: Service "app" uses an undefined network "host"`

Next try: define both networks explicitly and do not use the `network_mode: host` attribute at service level.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:

  app:
    build: .
    image: app
    container_name: app
    environment:
      - MONGODB_HOST=db
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - appnet
      - hostnet

  db:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    container_name: db
    networks:
      - appnet

networks:
  appnet: null
  hostnet:
    external:
      name: host
```

The foregoing compose file produces an error:

`ERROR: for app  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks`

**How to use the `host` network, and any other user-defined network (or the default) together in Docker-Compose?**

Answer (score 19):

TL;DR you can't. The host networking turns off the docker network namespace for that container. You can't have it both on and off at the same time.

Instead, connect to your database with a published port, or a unix socket that you can share as a volume. E.g. here's how to publish the port:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  app:
    build: .
    image: app
    container_name: app
    environment:
      - MONGODB_HOST=127.0.0.1

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and majorly overlooked. Published port gives the best of both worlds, with observability on localhost as well as private networking where the container services can resolve each other by container name.
Unfortunate reality is that you can't route packets into Docker for Mac from the host OS, but you can use published port to connect the containers to each other and the host OS.

Comment: This answer saved me. I'm using Docker Swarm so used this answer to do something similar. The container I put on the host network, I also added extra_hosts: 0.0.0.0:portNumber:PortNumber

Answer (score 1):

Since Docker 18.03+ one can use `host.docker.internal` to access your host from within your containers. No need to add `host` network or mix it with the user defined networks.

Source: [Docker Tip #65: Get Your Docker Host's IP Address from in a Container](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-65-get-your-docker-hosts-ip-address-from-in-a-container)

Comment: Only on Windows and macOS, on Linux this is currently depending on https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264

Comment: This is now implemented for Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use host network, you don't need to define it. Just use "ports" keyword to define, which port(s) from service you want to expose in host network.

Comment: `app` needs OSI layer 2 access to the host network. I am not asking for UDP/TCP port bindings.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did reproduce it on latest docker for windows - same issue. very similar issue is on moby github - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32957 - seems that this is a part of a bigger problem

Comment: Yes, I think the only way to use a multi container app with docker compose and host-networking is, to use host-network for all containers in the compose file. At least with the current version of Docker Compose of January 2018.

Comment: this answer helped me in a way that I removed the bridge network from container that had to use it, used `ports` directive for this container with internal networks related to other containers and also used `expose` for those other containers - it works like a charm