# Docker network bridge mapped with HOST OS network interfaces

Tags: docker, docker-network

Hi I am new in `docker network` . Basically I want to start a docker container that should be mapped with existing HOST OS network interface .

For e.g. List of HOST OS network interfaces

```
$>>ip a
1. ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000 
4. ens224: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
```

Now I want to create a Docker Network Bridge (mapped with ens192/ens224)  using

> $ docker network create -d bridge my-bridge-network

And then run the container using the `docker network`

> $ docker run -itd --network=my-bridge-network mydocker

But with mentioned steps I am not able to map `network interfaces` with `docker networks`.

Comment: A design goal of Docker is that containers can't directly access or administer the host interfaces.  You might be better off running this process directly on the host.  Possibly also see [How to use the host network, and any other user-defined network together in Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303141/how-to-use-the-host-network-and-any-other-user-defined-network-together-in-dock) (you can't).

Comment: That is correct for layer 3, but using a layer 2 tunnel can connect a container to "the outside network". But since it's barely used there is not much documentation for it... :(

Answer (score 2):

## The goal

Assuming that you want your Docker container to display to the network as an ordinary device, you can "map" a host interface using a `macvlan` bridge. What you will get:

- Docker clients receive an IP from the network the host is in
- Other devices can access the container as if it was in their physical network
- The container can access the same hosts as its host via the given interface

If that is not what you meant, please leave a comment and further explain your scenario.

## How it's done

Check weather `macvlan` module is installed using

```
lsmod | grep macvlan
```

If it is not listed, install it by issuing

```
modprobe macvlan
```

### Using Docker CLI

Create a network with the interface you want to share and specify subnet and gateway (gateway is optional if you want to use the internet via this network):

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=1.2.3.4/24 --gateway=1.2.3.1 -o parent=eth0 nice_name
```

(parent must be changed from `eth0` to your interface)

### Using Docker-Compose

You can also create those networks on-demand and include them in your `docker-compose.yml` files like in the following example:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  nginx1:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - nice_name

networks:
  private:
  nice_name:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth0  # change this
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "1.2.3.0/24" # change this
          gateway: "1.2.3.1" # change this (optional)

# Be aware that there is no "-" before "gateway" as it belongs to the subnet!
```

If you have already created the network outside of Docker-Compose, you can still connect clients to it that use Docker-Compose by using the `external` parameter:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  nginx1:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - nice_name

networks:
  nice_name:
    external: true
```

Comment: The comment for the `subnet` line says "change this". To what, exactly?

Comment: To whatever IP subnet you like. For example: If your local network is the typical 192.168.178.0/24, you should choose something different than 192.168.178.0/24 here to avoid routing conflicts and IP conflicts...